# Manage gradle version across multiple project

Tags: android, gradle, version

In this particular scenario I'm working on multiple Android project & each of using different gradle version.

Does anyone suggest about hot I should manage gradle version as per requirement instead downgrade & sync every time just because other project using other version.

Answer (score 0):

Just user different `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties` inside each project:

```
distributionUrl=\
  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-X.X.X-all.zip
```

Gradle will download the distribution and will cache it. In this way each project will use a different version without downgrade and sync every time.

Comment: This is what added as default. It still ask for update. I'll append exact scenario, might be I'm missing something as of now.

Comment: Do you use "Use default gradle wrapper" inside the project?